# RS232 Grounding question

Tags: ground, rs232

I want to connect 2 devices together using RS232.  I initially thought both devices used the power ground as the reference signal for their RS232 (they're powered by the same PSU) so I designed my RS232 cable just using Tx and Rx.  However, after some testing and some bad RS232 communication, I learned that one of the devices actually uses case ground (earth ground) as the reference signal.  If I connect the RS232 reference signal pin, the communication is flawless, but I want to avoid connecting my floating ground to earth ground (I believe this is good safety practice).  Is there someway I can create an isolated reference signal for the two devices to use?

Comment: > If I connect the RS232 reference signal pin
I'm confused by this statement. Are you saying you are trying to only use 2 wires between separate devices that are powered by the same PSU? so you are hoping to use the PSU ground for return ?

Comment: Tx & Rx use pin 7 as signal ground. The signal ground with the power ground will form a ground loop, so verify opto couplers for Tx/Rx.

Comment: @BrianOnn Yes, that's correct.  I have 3 devices all communicating RS232 with each other.  2 of them have RS232 ports that share use their power input 0V for the signal ground, and have flawless communication.  The third does not, and has issues.  I am only using 2 wires for communication.

Comment: @Optionparty Thanks, I'll look at optoisolation for RS232.

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope to check out what is wrong with your signal?

Comment: @jlandercy there is nothing wrong with the signal.  If I were to use a real RS232 cable to connect the device to a PC, communication is fine.  It's only because I wanted to use a minimal amount of wiring to connect everything together.

Answer (score 4):

You need to wire the signal ground (Pin 5 on DB-9 RS232) always.

Using only TX and RX is simply not a valid wiring IMHO. If it works, it's by accident and you are relying on the having the exact same ground potential on both sides. Which is ok for an internal UART connection within a device, but not between two separate devices.

If this causes a ground loops between two devices, or unwanted potential shifts, using fully opto-isolated RS232 as mentioned earlier is the only correct way.